# getting the name of an image from the directory and adding more than one MenuItem to Camera and DPI formula

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

1. I am currently able to get the directory of a file, is there a way to get the name of the file from the directory??
2. I want to add focusable Images in my app and want the images to fit a specific part of all blackberry screens, I heard about a DPI formula, 
   Please correct me if I am Wrong with my formula:

   `long h=Display.getHorizontalResolution();`
   `long v=Display.getVerticalResolution();`

   `long hv= h*v;//PPM`

   `double hvi=hv*  39.3700787 ;`

The `long h` and`long v`, give the same values and the answer to this formula is 3.710443460782276E9

1. One More thing, I have successfully figured out how to add one MenuItem to a Blackberry applications (I.E. the camera) but I am not quite sure how to add more than one. If you have any adivice, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double inchesInAMeter = 39.3700787; 
    double hvi= ((double) Display.getHorizontalResolution()) / inchesInAMeter;

    int widthdp = 100;

    int pixels = (int) (widthdp * (hvi / 160));

    LabelField LF = new LabelField(""+hvi);
    add(LF);
}

public static int convertDpToPx(int dp) {
    double inchesInAMeter = 39.3700787; 
    double hvi= ((double) Display.getHorizontalResolution()) / inchesInAMeter;
    int pixels = (int) (dp * (hvi / 160));
    return pixels;
}
```